# Is there any way to shorten a command in VIM?

Tags: vim

I use the plugin `NERDTree`, but every time I call it, I need to type

> :NERDTree

I can't use the `Esc`Key to help me to auto type the command, is there any way to reduce my typing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remap it to something easier:

```
" F12 toggles NERDTree
map <F12> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Or cmap it to :NT
cmap NT NERDTree
```

But anyway, you can just press `<Tab>` to autocomplete it after the first few characters.

```
:NER<Tab>
```

... autocompletes `:NERDTree`

Answer (score 1):

By default, command-line completion is done with the `<Tab>` key.  This can be configured with the `wildchar` option.

To complete using `<Esc>` instead, put the following in your vimrc:

```
set wildchar=<Esc>
```

For more information see `:help 'wildchar'`.