# Changing open command for NERDTree

Tags: vim, command, nerdtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to reduce the command in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371723/is-there-any-way-to-reduce-the-command-in-vim)

In vim to open your NERDTree menu you type :NERDTree, but that actually really annoys me, because it's long and mixed case. Since you close it with q, I want to open it with a short key (maybe **:n**, you can also provide suggestions for that if you feel like it). How can I change that?

I am sorry if this is simple, but I am a newb, and I don't know form where to start aproaching such a problem -from the plugin files, or is there a special remapping technique in your .vimrc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

to map NERDTree to any key you like (F2 in this example)

it's also possible to map it to :n

```
map :n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

but that's not very common, I like using one of the F-Keys because that's faster.